# angular carousel with slide show, reset after clicking on dot button, using rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, carousel

**working** sample is on this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ewhzct?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I am building angular carousel slider change component using rxjs. Each slides are chaged after 5 seconds. and currently woking fine. But my question is when clicking on `dot-button` the same clicked dot-slide brings back and shows that slide, but next change is not starting from where it was clicked previous, TO detect what I am saying in above stack blitz link if you click any dot see next slide will not start from where it was clicked. What I am doing currently is shown below ..

```
export class AppComponent {
   dotsLength;

   selectedDotIndexSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(undefined);
   selectedDotIndexSubject$ = this.selectedDotIndexSubject
   .asObservable()
   .pipe(
         switchMap(index => concat(of(index), of(undefined).pipe(delay(5000))))
    );

   readonly currentIndex$ = range(1, 3).pipe(
      concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(delay(5000))),
      repeat()
   );

   mainSlider$ = combineLatest([
       this.selectedDotIndexSubject$,
       this.currentIndex$
   ]).pipe(
          map(([selectedIndex, autoIndex]) => {
              return selectedIndex ?? autoIndex;
          })
    );
   readonly images = ["6027869", "3889926", "6027869"];
    ngOnInit() {
       this.dotsLength = new Array(this.images.length).fill(0);
    }
    dotClick(index: any) {
       this.selectedDotIndexSubject.next(index);
    }
}
```

as shown above code, I am combining two rxjs stream, one is click subject and other is range() operator with repeat() operator.

here is template file of component

```
<ng-container *ngIf="mainSlider$ | async as currentIndex">
    <h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
       {{currentIndex}}
            <p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
           <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index;" class="mySlides fade" [class.active]="i === currentIndex - 1">
           <div class="numbertext">{{ i + 1 }} / {{ images.length }}</div>
        <img
    [src]="'https://images.pexels.com/photos/' + image + '/pexels-photo-' + image + '.jpeg'">
        <div class="text">
            Caption {{ i + 1 }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <span *ngFor="let dots of dotsLength; let i = index;"
    [class.active]="currentIndex - 1  === i"
    #dot
    (click)="dotClick(i + 1)"
    class="dot">
 </span>
 </div>

 </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your count doesn't resume is because the counter isn't getting reset when you click.  So it immediately uses the clicked index, but then goes back to whatever would have been next.

The simplest way to get the counter to reset when manually clicking a dot is probably to spin up a new observable that emits at a steady interval.

You can use a single BehaviorSubject to emit the index of the clicked dot, which can be used to generate a new observable that emits at an interval starting from that index value.

```
  selectedIndexSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  currentIndex$ = this.selectedIndexSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(selectedIndex => timer(0, 2000).pipe(
      map(tick => (tick + selectedIndex) % this.imageIds.length)
    ))
  );

  dotClick(index: number) {
    this.selectedIndexSubject.next(index);
  }
```

I noticed you were using 1-based indexes in the template and 0-based in the controller.  I find it easier to just always use 0-based.  I know the `*ngIf` causes a problem when the unwrapped value is falsey (`0`), because it will hide your template when the index = 0.

There's a technique I like to use that overcomes this quite nicely, and that is to  expose a single observable to your view, that is an object that contains all the data your view needs.  This way, the object is never falsey, and any values that happen to be `0` are easily accessible.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66061421?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: On last question on this, how can we also make `touchStart` , `touchMove`, and `touchEnd` events to change slides. In mobile devices if we touchOn current slide and if we move it to right, then next, slide should comes in, and if we move to left previous slide comes in.?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66061421-bmqwck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts right-now I am doing touch slide changes like this. But this breaks pipe() cycle , is this correct way.. In mobile view of chrome dev tools slide changes from left or right.

Comment: I looked at your SB and I don't see the issue.  What do you mean "this breaks the pipe() cycle" ?  Perhaps this would be better explained in a separate question.